# Calling database object from different python modules

Tags: python, mysql, database, mariadb

I'm using MySQLdb module in Python 2.7 with a MariaDB database. I want to know how would be the proper way of using a database across multiple modules. I have this example in which I try to insert elements from another function into the database. I'm getting `OperationalError: (1046, 'No database selected')`

Edit: Here is the corrected code ([1](https://pastebin.com/6zVay9ep), [2](https://pastebin.com/A9rwiJe2)). Thanks. Know I would like a working example like this one with dependency injection.

This is the module in which I want to handle the database.

```
# test.py

import MySQLdb
import traceback
import test2 as insert_module
from warnings import filterwarnings

# Ignore MySQL `table already exists` warnings
filterwarnings ('ignore', category = MySQLdb.Warning)

# Create database object to keep it open as global variable
class  MyDB (object):
    connection = None
    cursor = None

    # Open database connection
    def  connect (self):
        self.connection = MySQLdb.connect ()
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor ()

    def  execute (self, sql, *args):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute (sql, *args)
            self.connection.commit ()
        except  MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print (traceback.format_exc())
            self.connection.rollback ()

    def  query (self, sql, *args):
        try:
            self.execute (sql, *args)
        # Reopen database connection
        except  ( AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError ):
            self.connect ()
            self.execute (sql, *args)

    def  disconnect (self):
        self.connection.close ()

db = MyDB ()

def  createDatabase ():
    db.query ("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Product")
    db.query ("USE Product")
    sql = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ProductColor` (
                `ProductID` VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
                `ColorID` VARCHAR(20)
            )"""
    db.query (sql)

def  insertProductColor (*args):
    sql = """INSERT INTO `ProductColor` VALUE (%s, %s)"""
    db.query (sql, args)

def  main ():
    createDatabase ()
    insert_module.processListOfProductColors ()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main ()
    db.disconnect ()
```

This is the module from which I want to insert the products.

```
#test2.py

import test as db_module

def  processListOfProductColors ():
    db_module.insertProductColor ("cup", "blue")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly unrelated but:

```
# Create database object to keep it open as global variable
class  MyDB (object):
    connection = None
    cursor = None
```

Those class attributes are useless - define them as instance attributes instead:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = None
        self.cursor = None
```

and while we're at it: DO NOT reuse the same cursor for all your queries. Else you're in for trouble when trying to execute another query while iterating over the results of a first one (and let's not talk multithreading...)

```
    # Open database connection
    def  connect (self):
        self.connection = MySQLdb.connect ()
```

You should certainly either check if you already have an opened connection, and if yes either close it first or just skip the `MySQLdb.connect()` call.

Also and FWIW, you have to pass connection infos (username, password, database name etc) to the `MySQLdb.connect()` call.  Your OperationalError comes from not passing a database name here.

```
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor ()
```

cf above : this will only get you troubles. Use a new cursor each time, that's the intended use of the dbapi.

```
    def  execute (self, sql, *args):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute (sql, *args)
```

cf above

```
            self.connection.commit ()
```

You should give the caller a way to NOT commit after each call - he may want to execute more than one statement in a single transaction (actually that's part of the point of having transactions...)

```
        except  MySQLdb.Error, e:
```

you want:

```
        except  MySQLdb.Error as e:

            print (traceback.format_exc())
```

Setup a logger (python's `logging` module) and call `logger.exception(...)` instead.

```
            self.connection.rollback ()
```

and ? Pretend it's ok ??? You want to re-raise the exception here obviously.

```
    def  query (self, sql, *args):
        try:
            self.execute (sql, *args)
```

Are you sure you want to commit transactions for read queries ???

```
        # Reopen database connection
        except  ( AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError ):
            self.connect ()
            self.execute (sql, *args)
```

Err... If the point was to lazily handle the connection then you failed. Look at python's support for computed attributes instead (`property` etc).

```
    def  disconnect (self):
        self.connection.close ()
```

More generally: trying to wrap the connection part in something that will gracefully (and eventually lazily) handle connection issues might be a good idea (but it's not that easy either...), but by all mean let the caller handle the cursor and transaction manually. A solution here could be to make `execute()` and `query()` [context managers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) that close the cursor and commit (or rollback) the transaction. Also remember that a bad exception handling is worst than no exception handling...

Comment: I'd like to see a correct class. I need to return some value to know if a `select` found an element as well as if a `query` was successful. [Here is the changed code](https://pastebin.com/vSV5WRf6). I've added raises to the exception handlers but I don't know what to do with them. I've added a commit method so the caller can handle the cursor and transaction manually.

Answer (score 0):

ideally, you should pass your DB object through dependency injection into the `insert_module` - since it doesn't look like you've set up your code like that, you could (**as a quick hack**, not the best solution) do:

`insert_module.processListOfProductColors (self.db)`

and then inside `processListOfProductColors(db)` use `db.insertProductColor` - as opposed to `db_module.insert...`

again, this is **not the best solution** without some refactoring, from what i can tell

**update**

here is a general example for dependency injection, which you can adapt for your own use:

```
# note that each class can be in a different module (file), 
# just make sure you import 

class db_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = create_db()

    @staticmethod
    def create_db():
        db = # create the db
        return db

class main(object):
    db = db_class()
    first_class = first_class(db) # dependency injection part 1
    first_class.whatever()
    # you can pass db to however many classes you want now 

class first_class(object):
    def __init__(self, db):
        self._db = db # dependency injection part 2

    def whatever(self):
        # do whatever with self._db
```

Comment: Could you show a working example with the proper way to do it?